# Printing Visifire Silverlight object

Tags: php, silverlight, visifire

I am using PHP.
There is a visifire chart object inserted into an html page with JavaScript.
When i print the page the chart is not displayed.
Is the a way to print it?

Comment: You could start by showing us what you've done....

Comment: it is too much code, but it is something like this: http://www.visifire.com/visifire_charts_gauges_documentation.php?target=silverlight   silverlight->charts->quickstart->working with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell me how are you exporting the chart? You Have to set [ToolBarEnabled](http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Reference/Attribute_Reference/ToolBarEnabled1.htm) property in Chart in order to print it?

Comment: I mean, not from the chart itself, but when I print the page form the browser.

Comment: @livil, You wont be able to print Silverlight object using the browser. You need to use Silverlight print functionality provided by Visifire. Check out the link http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Reference/Attribute_Reference/ToolBarEnabled1.htm

Comment: I mean with the browser's print functuinality

Comment: No.You cant print silverlight object using the browser's print functionality. You will have to use the silverlight print functionality provided by Visifire in order to print the chart. Please check the documentation http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Reference/Attribute_Reference/ToolBarEnabled1.htm